# Instagram API и ограничения

Tags: instagram-api

Изучаю инстаграм API, и нужен он мне для того чтобы оставлять на фотках авторизованного человека комментарии (*то есть,который авторизовался через мое приложение и получил TOKEN*). Естественно,что само приложение в **SANDBOX MODE** и кроме меня и моих аккаунтов его никто не будет использовать...

Интересует два вопроса:

1.Читая документацию и видя что что-то не клеится,наткнулся на ограничения в виде прохождения **апрува**.Никак не пойму,нужен ли он мне исходя из выше описанных целей?

2.Если да,можно ли его пройти(аппрув) при условии что нужен он для личных целей и само приложение состоит из двух PHP скриптов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если приложение будет работать с авторизоваными в твоей песочнице людьми, то тебе не нужно проходить апрув. Однако тут очень небольшие лимиты будут, в 10 раз меньше чем для апрув приложения. Для коментов кажется 20-30 запросов в час.

Пройти апрув в таком случае будет вряд ли возможно. Такое приложение не несёт пользы сообществу, а только своему владельцу. Можно попробовать все покрасивше оформить, снять скринкаст видео, написать terms and condition для него и попытаться убедить модераторов в том, что твое приложение нужно сообществу и пользователям.

Можно попробовать найти в продаже аккаунт с приложением, которое было создано до нововведений и проработает в старом режиме ещё до июня этого года.

Но шансы малы, я бы не тратил время. Увы, но после 17 ноября все тяжко стало.

Comment: тяжко стало? а можете подробнее рассказать. я только начал делать бота для инстаграм. заранее спасибо.

Comment: Та нечего рассказывать... Пока там все очень грустно выглядит на самом деле. Кроме парсер писать

Answer (score 1):

Изучайте Private API, на GitHub много кода по этой теме. Официально пройти review приложения у них не реально (по крайней мере, я не знаю и не слышал о подобных случаях, даже если у тебя проект с миллионом пользователей, то это их мало беспокоит). Такая политика Instagram в отношении своего API (а точнее головной компании Facebook).

Comment: https://spark.ru/startup/sociate-ru/blog/16102/delimsya-opitom-kak-projti-instagram-api-review